# Adding form to Wordpress post-editor

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I have a post type that lets people add an event, including the usual date, time, location fields that are added via custom meta boxes into an additional table

However, I have written a script that pulls in facebook event information from the event url, with the intention of populating the wordpress post editor fields with this information.

The problem is that this is a form, and cannot be added as a meta box, as it would create a form within a form. So what is there that I can use instead of creating a new meta box that will allow me to add this form to the post editor for this post type, preferably above the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it crucial that this form you're creating be it's own form?  If you're pulling in information from facebook, I'm assuming you want to save it somewhere in your DB when the post is saved, so why not just use the available post form, and save that data on post save?

If you absolutely have to have it be a separate form, you could try hooking in somewhere outside of the form (I can't think of a hook you could use off the top of my head, but if you need it, I could look), and then position with JS if necessary.

Comment: Im using AJAX to pull in information about an event through ajax and JSON. This information is used to populate the existing fields in the main post editor form (title, description, start/end date/time, location). Its basically just to make the whole process easier for clients, they can just click once and all the info is there, then add to it if desired. The info is then saved to the database as normal through the populated fields

Comment: I've managed to get a form to appear at the top of the page using admin_init and just echo'ing it out, but I dont know the hook to make an if statement for "if post-editor for post-type 'event'", and I cant find it in the codex. It also appears at the top of the page and looks a bit rubbish, until the rest of the form is loaded and it positions itself correctly, so I'm thinking this is not the way to do it.

Comment: I still don't quite understand - So you're pulling in information via ajax and JSON - that all sounds good.  You're using the information that was pulled in to populate fields in the post editor - like Title, description, etc - I get that part too.  What is the purpose of the form that you need to have separate from the edit post form?

Also, I can see how the wait time while the page/js loads would make putting the form somewhere else, and then positioning it with JS would look bad.

Comment: Because it's an AJAX form? I dont understand what you are suggesting.

Comment: So, the user has to enter some information (into this form), which you use to send a request to facebook, and then you populate/modify fields as necessary - is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, its just one text input that takes a url, sends to a php script that retrieves the JSON from the open graph. Then Jquery populates the form (or it will anyway). The purpose is just to make things quicker for the user, but then if they wish they can then add things to what is retrieved as they would any post, like videos and pictures and assign it to products (tickets)

Comment: So - if the form being sent out (to facebook) is only going to be handled via javascript, do you really need a real submit button?  Why not place the form in a meta box, as you originally did, but don't give it a submit button, give it a regular button with an id.  Then just watch for clicks on your button, and when you get them, take the content of the relevant facebook fields, and send them along via ajax (depending on the type of button you use, you might have to return false to ensure the form doesnt actually submit).

Comment: My knowledge of AJAX is really quite limited. So I dont need to specify a form action for it to work, I can just specify it in the AJAX configuration or whatever its called, to send the information to the php script? The form is being handled only by javascript on the front end, but is handled by a php script 'behind the scenes', but I think thats what you mean anyway.

Comment: As this seems to be the logical way to go about this, can you suggest a way to make the meta box appear above the title? As I would prefer it to be the first thign a user sees? Even when I set the priority as high it is still below the post editor